# How to find if the particular port is OPEN in Mobile using Java

Tags: android

In my application, I need to out if particular PORT is open on the Andriod Mobile Device using Java code. Please let me know how to achieve this using java

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `particular PORT`. What kind of port do you have in mind?